# Trying to RUN "npx hardhat compile" and getting openzeppellin error

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin

When i run `npx hardhat compile`

I get

```
    Solidity ^0.8.9; is not fully supported yet. You can still use Hardhat, but some features, like stack traces, might not work correctly.

Learn more at https://hardhat.org/reference/solidity-support

Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

  * contracts/Greeter.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol (^0.8.9)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol (^0.8.1)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-IERC20Permit.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol (^0.8.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol (^0.8.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
```

My Contract has:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol';
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
```

And my hardhat.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: '^0.8.9;',
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
```

Can´t find a solution for my error.
First time creating a contract.

My contract and hardhat.config.js file are matching... already tried to match the version of all mentioned files, but it still doest work.

Comment: can you share the code of harhad.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using additional symbols in the used Solidity version in your config

Change your config from `version: '^0.8.9;'` to `version: '0.8.9'`

```json
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: '0.8.9',
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
```